# Module ctypes has no attribute 'windll'

Tags: python, ctypes

i am running my web app on GCP app engine and and getting this error

```
AttributeError: module 'ctypes' has no attribute 'windll'
```

i am using it to display alert messages on browser, can anyone tell me the alternative or solution of this error

NOTE: i have also tried win32api but its not working as well here is the error

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==223 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (from versions: )
```

Comment: Are you running this on windows?

Comment: Apparently you're trying to use *Win* specific tools (modules, packages) on non *Win* environment. You'll have to post more details.

Comment: @CristiFati yes actually i am running it on Google Cloud Platform that is why so do ya have any alternative option to display alert messages on browser using python?

Comment: I don't know how *Google Cloud Platform* works, but you should either configure it to run your code on a *Win* instance, or remove all *Win* specific stuff from your code

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're trying to use a Windows module on a non Windows enviroment, if you check the ctype module it has some conditional classes:

```py
if _os.name == "nt":

    class WinDLL(CDLL):
        """This class represents a dll exporting functions using the
        Windows stdcall calling convention.
   [...]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html